# Spring boot data source initialization error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

```
2016-08-10 11:51:29.938  INFO 4336 --- [           main] com.employee.EmployeeApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-10 11:51:29.938 DEBUG 4336 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.employee.EmployeeApplication
2016-08-10 11:51:29.961 DEBUG 4336 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'classpath:/application.yml'
2016-08-10 11:51:29.961 DEBUG 4336 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'classpath:/application.yml' for profile default
2016-08-10 11:51:29.961  INFO 4336 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17486b3: startup date [Wed Aug 10 11:51:29 IST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1cabb2a
2016-08-10 11:51:29.970 DEBUG 4336 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Bean factory for org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17486b3: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@30646a: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,employeeApplication]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@70f8a6
2016-08-10 11:51:41.990 DEBUG 4336 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.AutoConfigurationPackages        : @EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the package 'com.employee'. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is enabled.
2016-08-10 11:51:42.472  WARN 4336 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-08-10 11:51:42.785  INFO 4336 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=d17d6c85-cdf2-3621-87fd-0420958f449a
2016-08-10 11:51:42.808  INFO 4336 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-08-10 11:51:43.091  INFO 4336 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12e0b249] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-10 11:51:43.233  INFO 4336 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2efab546] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-10 11:51:43.247  INFO 4336 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshEndpointAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshEndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d859b73c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-10 11:51:43.261 DEBUG 4336 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@e64760]
2016-08-10 11:51:43.261 DEBUG 4336 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Using ApplicationEventMulticaster [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@5fd2b1]
2016-08-10 11:51:44.354 DEBUG 4336 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\Shadab%20Ahmed\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.3.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar
2016-08-10 11:51:44.354 DEBUG 4336 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\Shadab%20Ahmed\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.3.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar
2016-08-10 11:51:44.356 DEBUG 4336 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.
2016-08-10 11:51:44.544  INFO 4336 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8091 (http)
2016-08-10 11:51:44.579  INFO 4336 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-08-10 11:51:44.583  INFO 4336 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
2016-08-10 11:51:45.030  INFO 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-08-10 11:51:45.031  INFO 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 15070 ms
2016-08-10 11:51:45.232 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Added existing Servlet initializer bean 'dispatcherServletRegistration'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration.class]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.114 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'metricFilter'; order=-2147483648, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.114 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'characterEncodingFilter'; order=-2147483648, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration.class]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.114 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'; order=-10000, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.114 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'httpPutFormContentFilter'; order=-9900, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.114 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'requestContextFilter'; order=-105, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.114 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'webRequestLoggingFilter'; order=2147483637, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/TraceWebFilterAutoConfiguration.class]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.114 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'applicationContextIdFilter'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration.class]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.127  INFO 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.142  INFO 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.143  INFO 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.143  INFO 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.143  INFO 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.143  INFO 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.143  INFO 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.143  INFO 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-10 11:51:46.225 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Initializing filter 'requestContextFilter'
2016-08-10 11:51:46.229 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured successfully
2016-08-10 11:51:46.230 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] iguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter : Initializing filter 'applicationContextIdFilter'
2016-08-10 11:51:46.230 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] iguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter : Filter 'applicationContextIdFilter' configured successfully
2016-08-10 11:51:46.231 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.b.c.w.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter : Initializing filter 'httpPutFormContentFilter'
2016-08-10 11:51:46.231 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.b.c.w.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter : Filter 'httpPutFormContentFilter' configured successfully
2016-08-10 11:51:46.231 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter      : Initializing filter 'metricFilter'
2016-08-10 11:51:46.231 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter      : Filter 'metricFilter' configured successfully
2016-08-10 11:51:46.231 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter  : Initializing filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'
2016-08-10 11:51:46.231 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter  : Filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' configured successfully
2016-08-10 11:51:46.231 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Initializing filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
2016-08-10 11:51:46.231 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured successfully
2016-08-10 11:51:46.231 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter      : Initializing filter 'webRequestLoggingFilter'
2016-08-10 11:51:46.231 DEBUG 4336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter      : Filter 'webRequestLoggingFilter' configured successfully
2016-08-10 11:51:46.338  WARN 4336 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2016-08-10 11:51:46.532  INFO 4336 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-08-10 11:51:46.734 ERROR 4336 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.employee.EmployeeApplication.main(EmployeeApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:180) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:121) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Application.yml file content is

```
server:
  port:
    8091
debug: true

spring:
  application:
    name: employee-app

---
spring:
  profiles: local

#hibernate config
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update


#Spring Boot Config for Oracle

  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
    username: system
    password: root

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: INFO


---
spring:
  profiles: default

#hibernate config
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

#Spring Boot Config for Oracle

    datasource:
       driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
       url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
       username: system
       password:  root

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: INFO
```

Comment: Can you clean up the formatting so it doesn't look like you just vomited up your question. Take the stacktrace into your favorite text editor and indent 4 spaces then paste it here. Same with any other file that you are pasting in.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It does not help to get a quick response to point out how urgent your issues is; it helps a lot more to provide a good context: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could you include your pom.xml? Is it possible that you didn't include the odbc jars?

Comment: @Shawn: another way to format as code is to select text and click the 'code' button in the post editor - even easier!

Comment: Nice... was always wondering how to do the indenting as you can't select and tab to indent.

Comment: With the data formatted I believe my answer is the correct issue and resolution. You need to move the "default" datasource properties into the top of the file and not under `default`

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines it looks like Spring doesn't know what database driver to use as none are specified. You created two profiles `default` and `local`. Unfortunately `default` is actually naming the profile and not what you think it was doing. If you want a default configuration you would just specify that in the application.yml not under a specific profile. Then when you activate a profile if there are setting in the profile it would override those defaults.

`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active)`

Comment: This is not my area, but the OP has a config file called `Application.yml` - does the initial cap matter?